# Genetic Programming Stackoverflow error

Tags: java, recursion

My code seems to do infinite recursion when I invoke it with trees of a greater depth.
I tried to do it without recursion, and well thats kinda difficult to do since i need to manipulate the tree itself, anyways here's is m code. Thanks

Problem is with the printPostOrder method, it gets to a leaf node and the goes back and forth printing that leaf node and its parent until the stack overflows

I'd rather I post my full code so that you can get what I'm I trying to do.

Node insertion is like this

```
import java.util.*;

public class IPG {

    class Node {

        private int arity;
        private String label;
        private int value;
        private Node[] children;
        protected int visit = 0;
        protected boolean isVisited = false;

        public Node(int arity, String label) {
            this.arity = arity;
            this.label = label;
            this.children = new Node[3];
        }

        public Node(Node another) {
            this.label = another.label;
            this.arity = another.arity;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return label;
        }

        String getLabel() {
            return label;
        }

        void insertChild(int pos, Node n) {
            if (pos < arity) {
                children[pos] = n;
            }
        }

        Node getChildAt(int i) {
            return children[i];
        }

        void setValue(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        int getArity() {
            return arity;
        }

        void replace(Node another) {
            this.arity = another.arity;
            this.children = another.children;
            this.label = another.label;
        }

    }

    private Node[] functions = { new Node(2, "AND"), new Node(2, "OR"),
            new Node(1, "NOT"), new Node(3, "IF") };

    private Node[] terminals = { new Node(0, "A0"), new Node(0, "D1"),
            new Node(0, "D0"), new Node(0, "A1"), new Node(0, "D2"),
            new Node(0, "D3"), new Node(0, "A2"), new Node(0, "D4"),
            new Node(0, "D5"), new Node(0, "D6"), new Node(0, "D7") };

    private Random random = new Random();

    private int multiplexerType = 3;

    public Node getTerminal() {
        return terminals[random.nextInt(multiplexerType)];
    }

    public Node getFunction() {

        return functions[random.nextInt(3)];
    }

    public Node getAnyNode() {
        return random.nextInt(2) == 1 ? getFunction() : getTerminal();
    }

    public Node generateGrow(int depth) {
        Node root;

        if (depth > 1)
            root = getAnyNode();

        else
            root = getTerminal();

        for (int i = 0; i < root.getArity(); i++)
            root.insertChild(i, generateGrow(depth - 1));

        return root;
    }

    public Node generateFull(int depth) {
        Node root;

        if (depth > 1)
            root = getFunction();

        else
            root = getTerminal();

        for (int i = 0; i < root.getArity(); i++)
            root.insertChild(i, generateFull(depth - 1));

        return root;
    }

    public void printPostOrder() {
        Node root = generateFull(3);
        printPostOrder(root);
    }

    private void printPostOrder(Node n) {
        if (n == null) {
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.println(n + " ");

            printPostOrder(n.children[0]);
            printPostOrder(n.children[1]);
            printPostOrder(n.children[2]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new IPG().printPostOrder();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? what is the error? where?

Comment: mind cutting the code short and showing the relevant part. http://sscce.org

Comment: What do you see when you step through a simple example in your debugger?

Comment: @PeterLawrey sometimes when I'm lucy it runs for Nodes of smaller depth, but ussually it just crashes from the get go

Comment: You'll need to show what's in generateFull because if your structure is a cyclical graph rather than a tree (I.e. a parent of one node is a child down the line), you'll keep going down in circles.

Comment: @beny23 Its a normal tree made up of nodes

Comment: Could you show the definition of getFunction or getTerminal or getArity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you are generating your `functions` array, you are only creating one node of each type, and then `getFunction()` re-uses these same nodes. What happens is that, if for example, you insert an "AND" node and its child is also an "AND" node, a cycle is created because they are actually the same object.

It's an easy fix, you just need to make sure to create a new node with each call of `getFunction()`, for example like so:

```
private String [] functionNames = {"AND", "OR", "NOT", "IF"};
private int [] functionArities = {2,2,1,3};

public Node getFunction() {
    int index = random.nextInt(3); // If you want to use "IF" nodes too this
                                   // needs to be nextInt(4)
    return new Node(functionArities[index],functionNodes[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance, that the graph is cyclic. Just because you use pre-created nodes and choose them randomly. The deeper the node, the higher the probability, that one node is inserted more then once. And in that case, you have your cycle and the JVM complains with a SSO.

The root of your problem is the `functions` array (`terminals` is OK, because a terminal node does not have any children).

Remove that array and create a **new** function object for each node.

Comment: (The code parts that I mentioned are from a previous edit, where the complete class was visible. Asking to shorten the code was a bad advice in this case)

Comment: thanks, yep the problem was with the function terminal.....thanks a lot this was bugging me for ages